# How to select only needed points for a polygon in php?

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a list of coordinates points from an area. How can I select from that array of points only the points that I need to make the outline of the polygon?

If I put all those points on the map the result is not good because is not a closed polygon and also is not an optimize functionality as I want to do this for multiple areas.

The array is in PHP and the output will be in Google maps. The Google maps part I know how to make but the PHP filter function I do not know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at Convex Hull algorithms (yup, it's an unlikely search term if you haven't heard of it before).  Once you comprehend them, then the programming will be much easier.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms

Comment: Thank you for this! Do you know if there is a class already created for this?

Comment: After a little bit of search I've found http://www.westhoffswelt.de/blog/2009/10/21/calculate-a-convex-hull-the-quickhull-algorithm